# how to hide spinner after the content loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

I'm using pjax to load content and while the content is loading, I show a spinner:

```
$('a[data-pjax]').pjax().live ("click", function () {
    $("#loader").show();
});
```

This works fine, however, after the content loads the `loader` still stays there.

Where should I call `$(#loader).hide()` to hide the loader after the content has loaded?

Comment: Call `show()` before the `ajax call` and then in callback function call `hide()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the doc https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

```
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
  $("#loader").hide()
})
```

I think you can also use pjax:end event.

Answer (score 2):

of course after the content loads, after your ajax call within the success function.

```
$.ajax({
          url: "test.html",
          data: {parameter:parameter},
          }).done(function() {
               //on return, add here
               $("#loader").hide()
          });
```